# ajaxProgressiveLoad="load", initialFilter and ajaxURLGenerator

Tags: tabulator

Im using an ajaxProgressiveLoad="load" successfully, but intialFilter doesnt seem to get applied during the load, as all the rows are displayed. Also, the calculation for the last_page response from the server is quite expensive (and will get more so!) so I was trying to use ajaxURLGenerator to include a last_page=getPageMax() request parameter to tell my server that it has already calculated the last_page already, and just return this value. But getPageMax() returns false, as detailed in the docs to indicate that pagination is not being used.

So at the moment, I'm under the impression that these 2 features/functions are not available under progressiveLoad ? If not, is there another way around to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using progressive loading then i would suggest that you use ***ajaxFiltering*** option to pass the filter information back to the server and filter it server side to reduce the amount of data sent in the request.

```
ajaxFiltering=true
```

The ***getPageMax*** function is only available when pagination is being used explicitly, not when progressive loading is being used

Importantly the ***last_page*** value is primarily used in this instance to let Tabulator know that there are still more pages to load, you could effectively always return this value as 1 or 2 above the current page while there is still information available and set it to the current page when you have reached the last set of records, that way it should continue to try and load data without the overhead of the final page calculation.

Comment: well I have 20k rows in the DB, currently getting 700 'Q' & 'D' rows in 200 line pages (only showing the 'D' rows for starters. But then I wanted to pull 6800 'F' rows, not shown. Then pull the remaining 12,500 'X' and 'C' rows on-demand. calculating the last_page on the 'F' rows takes 8sec, so i don't want to do it that often. I think with the limitation of the progressiveLoad atm, it might be better to do it myself and use the updateData()

Comment: Im afraid progressive load isnt designed to work that way, changing the filter triggers the download of data to start from the begging, you would either need to sort that server side or manually hand the process with updateData as you say